# Build path and call python with arguments

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a PowerShell script that works fine:

```
../third_party/python3/win_x86_64/python.exe fusion.py $args
```

Now obviously this only works if the current working directory is correct. So I added a variable `$abs_parent_path`.

Simply adding that in front sadly does not work:

```
$abs_parent_path/../third_party/python3/win_x86_64/python.exe fusion.py $args
```

Seems some magic of PowerShell is then breaking down.

Now the question to me is how to build the absolute path to Python and Invocate.

Comment: Can you try this: `& (Join-Path $abs_parent_path "/../third_party/python3/win_x86_64/python.exe") fusion.py $args`

Comment: Leads to `UnexpectedToken`.

Comment: Actually I was missing the `&`. Now it complains `ParameterBindingValidationException` for `$abs_parent_path`.

Comment: is python executable in a well know path? why can't you hardcode it?

Comment: The example path illustrates that it is relative to another path. And this other path is different between Systems.

Comment: Problem was that `$abs_parent_path` had an invalid value. So your suggestion should have worked @MartinBrandl. Thx.